# Why Python server only recieves once

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to make a very simple python server and one python client to connect to it, However, this is my code:

**SERVER:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

""" 
A simple echo server 
""" 

import socket 
import sys

host = '' 
port = 50000 
backlog = 5 
size = 1024 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(backlog) 
while True: 
    client, address = s.accept() 
    data = client.recv(size) 
    if data: 
        client.send(data) 

    if data.decode('UTF-8') is 'exit':
        client.close()
        break
sys.exit()
```

**CLIENT:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

""" 
A simple echo client 
""" 

import socket 

host = 'localhost' 
port = 50000 
size = 1024 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((host,port))

while True:
    t = input('Enter Text: ')
    s.send(bytes(t, 'UTF-8'))
    data = s.recv(size) 
    print ('Received:', data.decode('UTF-8'))

    ans = input('Do you want to send another text? (y/n): ') 
    if ans is 'n' or ans is 'N':
        break

print ("Thank you for using my software...")
print ("Have a nice day")

s.send(bytes('exit', 'UTF-8'))
s.close()
```

I have read multiple similar questions, yet no one matches my problem, as they all used more complicated processes.
As you can see It's a very simple application, and it's my first one.

Comment: Don't compare strings with `is`. That's for checking object equality (same memory address). Use `==` to check value equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving data only once per client.

```
while True: 
    client, address = s.accept() 
    data = client.recv(size) 
    if data: 
        client.send(data) 

    if data.decode('UTF-8') is 'exit':
        client.close()
        break
```

In this part of the code, you are accepting each client connection using `client, address = s.accept()` and then calling `data = client.recv(size)` to receive the data from that client only once.

What you need to do is at the most basic level, spawn a new thread to handle the communication with the client.

```
client_thread = ServiceThread(client)
client_thread.start()
```

Add the above code once you accept the connection - where `ServiceThread` is a new thread that is used just for this client.

```
while True: 
        client = s.accept() 
        client_thread = ServiceThread(client)
        client_thread.start()
```

You can then choose to do whatever you want with the client in that thread. As a rough example:

```
from threading import Thread

class ServiceThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, client):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = client[0]
        self.addr = client[1]

    def run(self):
        data = self.conn.recv(1024) 
        if data:
            self.conn.send(data)
```

Comment: How am I suppose to do that? And what if I don't want to use threads? is that possible? I don't want to make a pro version. I want it as simple as possible

Comment: If you want to be able to handle multiple clients, you CANNOT avoid using multithreading. The code I have written is most rudimentary and there are other sophisticated methods for the same.

Comment: Well @Roshdy its a matter of having it work correctly or not - there is nothing "pro" or "amateur" about it :)

Comment: I did exactly like you said, the server keeps giving me: **NameError: name 'ServiceThread' is not defined**. I used `import threading`, still the same error

Comment: @gravetii I want it for only one client, but i want this client to send and receive multiple times, that's all

Comment: @Roshdy Of course, it gives you the error - you need to write the Thread to give it your implementation. Check my updated answer that roughly tells you what to put in in the Thread class.

Comment: thanks @gravetii I think I'll have to read more to use threading. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Roshdy Yes, give it some good reading. http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html